# Android GLSurfaceView causes leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, glsurfaceview

I am trying to use `GLSurfaceView` on Android and  experiencing problems.
I am using the code from [this OpenGL article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).
It works well but when I rotate the device, I notice that the allocated memory is growing.

So I use [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to check if I have a memory leak and found that there are multiple `Activity` instances there. If I use dominator tree, I found multiple `GLThread` objects (but only one is running).
So is this an android `GLSurfaceview` bug or I'm misunderstanding something about `GLSurfaceView`?

Comment: do anybody have answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly caused by referring to the `Activity` context instead of referring to the `Application` context. When referring to `context`, always use `getApplicationContext()` inside the `Activity`. Avoid using `this` (inside the `Activity`) class as it refers to the `Activity`.